# Dynamic array, filtering and sorting

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a list of course units that i want to display via a drop down list depending on the "Course Name" i want to have all the "Unit code" and "Unit name" displayed accordingly

In the sheet named "Units list" i have the corresponding data but I want to avoid double ups, I only need each unit in that table once. So I need somehow to have one unit linked to one or more course

[image]

[image]

Comment: So the user is selecting from the *Course Name* column with a drop down. And if they select, say *Diploma of Business*, you want to show *BSB01* in `B5`, *BSB02* in `B6`, *Plan risks* in `C5`, and *Manage risks* in `C6`, is that correct?

Comment: Exactly what is your question??

Comment: @ChristoferWeber thats exactly correct!

Comment: @teylyn its exactly what Christofer Weber said!

Comment: @MerajAhmed,, if this is what U r looking for `And if they select, say Diploma of Business, you want to show BSB01 in B5, BSB02 in B6, Plan risks in C5, and Manage risks in C6, is that` then in cell B5 & B6 you need to enter lookup formula !!

Comment: To de-dupe the data validation input list, create a pivot table of your Course Name list with Course Names in the Rows, then create a Named Range referring to a formula `=OFFSET('Units list'!$G$6,0,0,COUNTA('Units list'!$G$6:$G$24),1)` (where the pivoted list starts in `G6`), and feed that named range into your data validation control.

Answer (score 1):

If you have Office 365 Excel with dynamic arrays, as suggested by your question referring to `Dynamic array`, then:

```
B5:=INDEX(FILTER(courseCodes,courseCodes[Course Name]=$C$2),0,1)
C5:=INDEX(FILTER(courseCodes,courseCodes[Course Name]=$C$2),0,2)
```

Where `courseCodes` is a named `Table` referring to your table on the `Units List` worksheet.

Note that you only need to enter the formula in the designated cell. The additional results will `spill down` to show all the results.

*And thanks to @teylyn for pointing out that this is a feature of Excel/O365 and not Excel 2016+*

[image]

@AlexM noted that I did not address de-duping the Course Names, I presume for your dropdown.  If you have Dynamic arrays, then you have the `UNIQUE` function, so you can create a unique list for your drop-down with the formula:

```
=UNIQUE(courseCodes[Course Name])
```

entered someplace on a worksheet. And then refer to it by the Named formula (assuming it is on the `Units List` worksheet starting in `J1`:

```
Courses refers to: ='Units List'!$J$1:INDEX('Units List'!$J:$J,COUNTA('Units List'!$J:$J))
```

In your Data Validation List box, you would then enter `=Courses`

Comment: Ron, that sounds as if all Excel 2016+ has dynamic arrays. Only Excel 365 has Dynamic arrays, and the slow updating semi-annual channel still doesn't.

Comment: This answer does not address deduping the data validation list

Comment: @teylyn Didn't realize that differentiation.  Too many versions :-).  I never signed up for anything special and I've got them.  And he did mention `Dynamic Arrays` in the title to his question. But I'll edit my answer to point that out.

Comment: @AlexM Yes, you're correct. If he has dynamic arrays, then he has the `UNIQUE` function and should be able to create a deduped list.  But I'll edit my response to point that out specifically.